# Customize default queries generated by Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Is this possible to customize default queries that are generated for findAll and findById generated by Spring Data REST ? For example, selecting a subset of columns , since I found that setting @JsonIgnore does not change the SELECT columns itself in query generated.

Search queries can be customized by @Query but not sure how to do with other links like for all users or users/{id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said search queries can be customised by @Query, so you can just override default methods with Query annotation in your interface declaration

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

       @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname like %?1")
       List<User> findAll();

       @Query("select u from User u where u.id == %?1")
       User findById(String id);
    }
```

If you want to select subset of columns, I would suggest to create new entity with public columns, that would be mapped to the same table as internal presentation.

```
   class UserPublic
   ... public fields;
```

And open API based on new entity repository

```
    public interface UserPublicRepository extends JpaRepository<UserPublic, Long> {}
```

Comment: I think UserPublicRepository will be UserPublic as JpaRepository generic type ?

Comment: also how can we control query generated for projections ?  Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524529/how-to-control-sql-query-generated-during-spring-data-rest-projections